# Rotary Wheel stopping at every 90 degree sector only iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made a rotary wheel of 26 sectors. I want the rotary wheel to stop randomly at any of the sectors whereas it is only stopping at every 90 degrees sector (on sector # 0,6,13,20). This is my code snippet.

```
// an ivar for your class:
BOOL animating;

- (void) spinWithOptions: (UIViewAnimationOptions) options {
   // this spin completes 360 degrees every 2 seconds
   [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5f
                         delay: 0.0f
                       options: options
                    animations: ^{
                       self.imageToMove.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageToMove.transform, M_PI / 2);
                    }
                    completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                       if (finished) {
                          if (animating) {
                             // if flag still set, keep spinning with constant speed
                             [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
                          } else if (options != UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) {
                             // one last spin, with deceleration
                             [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut];
                          }
                       }
                    }];
}

- (void) startSpin {
   if (!animating) {
      animating = YES;
      [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn];
   }   
}

- (void) stopSpin {
    // set the flag to stop spinning after one last 90 degree increment
    animating = NO;
}
```

Please tell me how to make it stop randomly every time it spins.

Comment: 26 segments is tricky since 360/26 isn't a whole number. You transform rotates by Pi/2 radians (90 degrees) each time. You need to rotate by 13.8461 degrees each time which is approximately M_PI_2/6.49 radians

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works :)

Comment: Hi, if i implement your solution the animation of the wheel does not look real time. i.e ease in and ease out effect is not showing.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I have made following method for selection of segment randomly.

numberOfSections is number of segment in wheel.and angleSize is calculated as below :

angleSize = 2*M_PI/numberOfSections;

- (void)pressSpin {

  ```
  CGFloat randValue= (arc4random() % numberOfSections)+numberOfSections;
  angleRotate =  (randValue * angleSize)*2;
  CABasicAnimation *spinAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
  spinAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:angleSize];
  spinAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:angleSize+angleRotate];
  spinAnimation.duration = 2.0f;
  spinAnimation.cumulative = YES;
  spinAnimation.additive = YES;
  spinAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
  spinAnimation.delegate = self;
  spinAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction
                                  functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
  spinAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
  [container.layer addAnimation:spinAnimation forKey:@"spinAnimation"];

  }
  ```